# Is the specific heat of salt the same as Na + CL when dissolved?

Tags: aqueous-solution

I had this question when my friends were discussing how salt influences boiling time.  When crystal salt is dissolved into water, it turns into a single Na and a single Cl atom.  If knew the total heat capacity of the salt I want to add to my water, could I be confident, that when dissolved, total heat capacity I added to the water is equal to the undissolved salt's heat capacity?

On one hand my intuition tells me that heat capacity should remain the same.  Salt is salt.

On the other, doesn't the salt lose a rotational vibration mode when is dissolves into its two monatomic elements?

I am not trained in chemistry, so sorry if this is a naive question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt does not dissolve to to $\ce{Na}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ atoms, but to hydrated $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions, so it's heat capacity is very different to the solid $\ce{NaCl}$.

And yes it looses vibration modes of the crystal lattice, less the rotation, as there is nothing to rotate in the lattice.

There are also vibrations of coordination bonds to water. Dissolved ions also have translational degrees of freedom, what is missing in solids.

Even for the identical substance, its heat capacity in solid and liquid state differ. E.g. liquid water has about 2x bigger heat capacity than ice ( 4.2 versus 2.1 J/g/K ).